# Prove $(a+b+c)^2 - 9ab > 0$ if a,b,c ≥ 0

Tags: inequality

Prove $(a+b+c)^2 - 9ab > 0$ ,

if $a,b,c$ are real and $ 0≤ a ≤ b ≤ c$

I'm not sure where to start, I've tried expanding but I think I must have missed something.

$(a + b + c)^2 − 9ab = (a^2 + b^2+c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ca) − 9ab$

P.S. This is for homework, so I want to understand what the steps are and where to start, but try not to give everything away, please.
Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Have a look at the AM-GM (arithmetic mean, geometric mean) inequality for three numbers

Comment: Sure about this?  What about $a=b=1$ and $c =\frac 12$.  Then $a+b+c < 3$ so $(a+b+c)^2 < 9 = 9ab$ so $(a+b + c)^2 - 9ab < 0$.  .... Did you mean $(a+b+c)^2 - 9abc > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove this statement because it is not true. Take $a=b=c=1$ as a counterexample, in which case you get $$(a+b+c)^2 - 9ab = 0$$ and it is not true that $0>0$.

If you set $c$ to a value smaller than one, you actually get $(a+b+c)^2-9ab < 0$, so even if the inequality at the start is changed to $\geq$, the result is still false.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing $a,b$ with their mean will only reduce the LHS (why?), so it is enough to show this holds true for $a=b$.

Further, as the inequality and constraints are both homogeneous, we can scale as desired, so WLOG, let $a=b=1$, $c\geqslant 1$.

Now you have a quadratic in one variable $c$, can you find when it's sign changes and whether the inequality holds true in the region $c\geqslant 1$?

---

P.S.

1. Do recheck if your inequality is $>$ sign or has the $\geqslant$  sign wherever you got the problem from.
2. Actually with just the first argument you can reduce to checking the case $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Ah.   That $c \ge a; c\ge b$.  is key.  (Otherwise it isn't true)

$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ac$.

As $c \ge b\ge a$ then $ac \ge ab;bc \ge ab; c^2 \ge ab; b^2 \ge ab$ but but unfortunately $a^2 \le ab$.

But otherwise we have $(a+b+c)^2 \ge a^2 + 8ab$.

What we really need is to show $a^2 + c^2 \ge 2ab$ to be done.

But that looks like the A.M/G.M. is inequality.

$a^2 + c^2 \ge 2\sqrt{a^2c^2} = 2ac$.  (or alternatively $(a-c)^2 \ge 0$ so $a^2 - 2ac +c^2 \ge 0$ and $a^2 + c^2 \ge 2ac$.

So that'll do it.

$(a+b+c)^2 = (a^2 + c^2) + b^2 + 2(ab + bc + ac) \ge$

$2ac + b^2 + 2(ab + bc +ac) \ge 2ab + ab + 2(2ab) = 9ab$

.... except... that is *not* strictly greater than as if $a=b=c$ we'd have equality.

However if $c > b$ or $b > a$ or $c > a$ we'd have a strict inequality.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(a+b+c)^2-9ab&\ge (a+2b)^2-9ab\\
&=a^2-5ab+4b^2\\
&=(b-a)(4b-a)\\
&\ge0
\end{align}